# Regex to validate a filename

Tags: java, regex, file

I need to validate a in a method like this.

```
    validateFileName(Editable s) {
        String filtered_str = s.toString();
        if (filtered_str.matches(".*[regexp].*")) {
            filtered_str = filtered_str.replaceAll("[regxp]", "");
            s.clear();
            s.append(filtered_str);}
```

Which regexps should  i use to exclude all illegal characters and white-spaces? I'm using linux

Comment: The only illegal characters in a filename on a Unix filesystem are `/` (path separator) and `\0` (end of string in C).

Comment: You might want to exclude the following from being considered as filenames in their own right too: `.`, `~`, `#`, `-`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your idea is only to exclude ilegal and space char you can use something like:

`'^[^*&%\s]+$'`

where you can add any "ilegal" char into the list of chars (in this case it ignores *, &, % and space)  `\s` is the space! The `^` inside the `[]` is part of the regex syntax it means: do **not** match any chars inside `[]`.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using a POSIX-compliant operating system, the legal characters in a file name are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, period, underscore, and hyphen. The regex to match 'illegal' characters would therefore be

`[^-_.A-Za-z0-9]`

Addendum: This is if you want a fully-portable file name. As I was corrected in Josip's comment below, POSIX itself actually allows more characters.

Comment: This appears to be incorrect, because http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html says only "The bytes composing the name shall not contain the <NUL> or <slash> characters." in the section 3.170 Filename.

Comment: Ah, yes. I should have clarified in my answer that if you want a **fully portable** filename, you would use the regex I described. This came from the book _POSIX Programmer's Guide: Writing Portable UNIX Programs_ by Donald Lewine (1991), pp. 63-64.

Comment: That's still very restrictive, which is understandable for 1991, but not really these days, when e.g. commas and spaces in filenames are so common among the users. They would probably complain if you applied this, and adherence to limits from the 80s wouldn't necessarily be considered a reasonable rationale.